# how to show variables in sweetalert2

Tags: javascript, sweetalert2

I am trying to use sweetalert2 which seems to be good as easy to implement modals but it seems to be limited or I am just being thick. All I am trying to do is when it is activated I want it to show a javascript variable but it seems I cannot do this without JSON and loading all sorts? Is it me or am I being thick?

The var I want to show is this

```
            var ad1 = test5+' '+place.formatted_address;
```

and the way I am trying to show it is :

```
swal("details", "details 2"+ad1)
```

})

Doing my head in, I have never used modals before either by the way but thanks for any help

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: Nope? Even tried with the html output and tried to output PHP variables but no good??? Sort of getting the feeling its designed for alerts and warnings only but surely it should allow for custom information to be added?

Comment: yeah definitely, if it allows passing in string, then it should also allow variables in this manner because the end result it gets is still a string

Comment: Does it work fine if you alert a plain string e.g. `swal("details", "details 2")` ???

Comment: yes, but the details and details  are only text not variables

Comment: Do  all the variables exist? If not then that might be the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added a variable here and it works just fine. Can you check if this is what you want:

```js
var testVar = "TestVariable";

swal({
  title: "Error!",
  text: "Here's my " + testVar,
  type: "error",
  confirmButtonText: "Cool" 
 });
```

```html
<script src="http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert-dev.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.css">
```

Comment: Yours works great but when I add it I get 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input' error on the console?

Comment: I have it on included also like $(document).ready(function() {

Comment: Sorted thankyou, I deleted }); from the original $(document).ready(function() {, Thanks

Comment: ok, now another problem, its not loading vars from a different js script? I gt this error Uncaught ReferenceError: place is not defined
    at HTMLLIElement.<anonymous> (gb31.php:113)
    at HTMLLIElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
    at HTMLLIElement.q.handle (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)

Comment: Its ok I saved them like this and just loaded them           document.getElementById('show_pick_up_modal').innerHTML = test5+' '+place.formatted_address;

Comment: @Mia Sorry I checked your comments just now. Glad you sorted it yourself :)